# PHP Regex | Вырезка значений из тега span

Tags: php

Прошу помочь с вырезкой значения из этого html кода:

```
<span class="" style="color:#2ab27b">Работает/Working</span>
```

Требуется вырезать "Работает/Working".

Comment: Ну можно попробовать так `>(.+)<\/span>`, а вообще, не совсем понятно, что вы хотите сделать.

Comment: Имеется строка: <span class="" style="color:#2ab27b">Работает/Working</span>
Из нее надо вырезать значение между тегами <span> значение </span>

Answer (score 3):

```
$str = '<span class="" style="color:#2ab27b">Работает/Working</span>';

echo strip_tags($str) . PHP_EOL;

echo str_replace(strip_tags($str), '', $str);
```

Вывод

```
Работает/Working
<span class="" style="color:#2ab27b"></span>
```

[Выполнить код](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/670c80e6140b37c1199def371368b0107c1a3d08)